# Container width position:fixed jumps to the left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, affix

I try to figure it if it is a Bootstrap Affix problem, or just a tiny CSS error.

When the navigation starts to fix on the top it jumps to the left and I have no idea why this happens.

Link: http://new.myshirtstore.de

Comment: It's impossible to extract the relevant code, because of too many nested files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was pretty simple to figure out...

You have a ID of `#topmenu` and this element has a `width` of `Inherit` All you need to do is give this a new `width` of `100%`

`width: Inherit` Inherits the property from its parent element which is causing you navbar to jump to the left!

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp

Your new #topmenu should look like this:

```
#topmenu {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 0;
    background: #ebedef;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #95bf0c;
}
```

Comment: You are awesome. I was focussed to the position details.